# Customizr Wordpress- Remove on hover effect on blog grid on main page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to remove the onhover effect on the blog list on main page.
Currently on hovering on any of the blog title or image, an image with a pencil icon in it appears.

While browsing on mobile device, we have to click twice on the featured image, as the first click shows the onhover effect and on second click it actually receives a click.

Following is the link:
http://kkdigitals.com/wordpresswall/

Answer (score 0):

you can hide the pencil by using following css

```
.tc-grid-icon{z-index:0 !important}
```

please also use this Js code:

```
jQuery("article").off("hover");
```

Comment: Tried it! It just removes the pencil icon but still while browsing on mobile devices I have to click twice

Comment: @Jitu, please put "jQuery("article").off("hover")" in your custom js file

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but where to put this JS code? I know Where to put custom css code but no idea about Custom JS

Comment: check this post: https://www.godaddy.com/garage/webpro/wordpress/3-ways-to-insert-javascript-into-wordpress-pages-or-posts/